# Real locus of a cone or a double cone

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

If we take the algebraic set of $X^2+Y^2-Z^2=0$, $V(X^2+Y^2-Z^2)$, why do we obtain a single cone, rather than the real locus of $X^2+Y^2-Z^2$ being a double cone? This seems absolutely wrong, since $(-z)^2=z^2$ obviously. Is there something more going on here?

[Cones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTWw6.png)

Comment: I think the locus **is** a double cone. Who says it isn't?

Comment: @bubba Good to hear, see attached picture for James Milnes text excerpt.

Comment: @Timothy I take it you took that excerpt from http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG.pdf. Indeed I could find no condition in the surrounding context which would reduce this to a single cone. But also note that the *text* does *not* explicitly say that it's a *single* cone. For some people, cones are double cones by default unless stated otherwise. The *figure* is obviously that of a single cone, though, so taken together this looks not merely confusing but plain wrong to me.

Comment: @MvG Thanks!   -T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm answering to get this out of the unanswered queue.*

$X^2+Y^2-Z^2=0$ without any further restrictions *does* describe a double cone.
People who just call it “cone” might be lazy, and might have established a convention where “cone” without qualification means “double cone”.
People who call it a “single cone”, or depict it as such, are in my opinion just wrong.